# Subset problem in python - fix the number of addends that sum to the target

Tags: python, subset-sum

I'm trying to implement a simple program that aims to solve the subset problem in python. 
I've found the following code that involves dynamically programming:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, partial=[]):
    s = sum(partial)

    # check if the partial sum is equals to target
    if s == target: 
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))
    if s >= target:
        return  # if we reach the number why bother to continue

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, partial + [n])
```

The code works but it finds all the possible combinations, while I'm only interested on subsets with a maximum number of addends that I want to specify time to time.

In other words I'd like to set a maximum number of the internal loops. To do that I've written the following code that considers all the possible combinations of at most 4 numbers that sum to the target (i.e. 3 internal loops)

```
def subset_sum(n_list, tot):

    cnd = n_list[n_list < tot]
    s = np.sort(cnd)
    n_max = len(cnd)

    possibilities = []

    for i1 in range(n_max):
        i2 = i1+1

        while (i2<n_max)and(s[i1]+s[i2]<=tot):
            if (s[i1]+s[i2]==tot):
                possibilities.append([s[i1],s[i2]])
            i3 = i2+1

            while (i3<n_max)and(s[i1]+s[i2]+s[i3]<=tot):
                if (s[i1]+s[i2]+s[i3]==tot):
                    possibilities.append([s[i1],s[i2],s[i3]])
                i4 = i3+1

                while (i4<n_max)and(s[i1]+s[i2]+s[i3]+s[i4]<=tot):
                    if (s[i1]+s[i2]+s[i3]+s[i4]==tot):
                        possibilities.append([s[i1],s[i2],s[i3],s[i4]])

                    i4+=1
                i3+=1
            i2+=1 
    return possibilities
```

This code works pretty well, can also be speed up with numba (while the first code no) but I cannot fix the maximum number of addends. 
Is there a way to implement the function subset_sum with an extra argument that fix the maximum number of addends that sum to the target?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are adding a number in each recursion you can just limit the recursion depth. To do so, you need to add a new parameter to control the maximum depth (a.k.a. the maximum number of addends).

Here is the code:

```
def subset_sum(numbers, target, num_elems, partial=[]):
    # Check if the partial sum is equals to target                                                                                                                                                                                          
    s = sum(partial)
    if s == target:
        print("sum(%s)=%s" % (partial, target))

    # If we have surpassed the number there is no point to continue
    if s >= target:
        return
    # If we have surpassed the number of elements there is no point to continue
    if len(partial) >= num_elems:
        return

    # Otherwise go through the remaining numbers
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        n = numbers[i]
        remaining = numbers[i+1:]
        subset_sum(remaining, target, num_elems, partial + [n])
```

You can run it with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    num_elems = 3
    target = 10
    p = []
    subset_sum(nums, target, num_elems, p)
```

And the output will be:

```
sum([1, 4, 5])=10
sum([2, 3, 5])=10
```

Notice that the combination of 4 elements (`[1, 2, 3, 4]`) is not shown.

---

**EDIT:**

To speed-up the above code with Numba you need to build an iterative version of it. Since you are basically computing the combinations of `numbers` in sets of `num_elements` size, you can check the iterative implementation of the `itertools.combination` (more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)). Based on that implementation you can obtain the following code:

```
def subset_sum_iter(numbers, target, num_elements):
    # General: we iterate among the indexes and build each solution by taking the values in those indexes

    # Initialize solutions list
    solutions = []

    # Build first index by taking the first num_elements from the numbers
    indices = list(range(num_elements))
    solution = [numbers[i] for i in indices]
    if sum(solution) == target:
        solutions.append(solution)

    # We iterate over the rest of the indices until we have tried all combinations
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(num_elements)):
            if indices[i] != i + len(numbers) - num_elements:
                break
        else:
            # No combinations left
            break

        # Increase current index and all its following ones
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, num_elements):
            indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1

        # Check current solution
        solution = [numbers[i] for i in indices]
        if sum(solution) == target:
            solutions.append(solution)

    # Print all valid solutions
    for sol in solutions:
        print ("sum(" + str(sol) + ")=" + str(target))
```

Which can be run with:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    num_elems = 3
    target = 10

    # Calling iterative subset
    subset_sum_iter(nums, target, num_elems)
```

And outputs:

```
sum([1, 4, 5])=10
sum([2, 3, 5])=10
```

As in the previous case, notice that only the combinations with 3 elements are shown.

Comment: Thanks this works pretty well! However in this way I cannot use numba to speed up the code. Do you think there might be a way to speed it up?

Comment: @Lorenzo I have added an iterative version that can be speed-up with Numba. Haven't check the performance difference though. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Lorenzo Consider accepting the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you prefer combinations or permuations here, but you could try this?

```
import itertools
limit = 1 #number of addends
possibilities = 0
combinations = []
not_possibilties = 0
number_addends = 4
while(limit <= number_addends):
    for comb in itertools.combinations([number_list], limit):
        if sum(comb) == target:
            possibilities +=1
            combinations.append(comb)
        else:
            not_possiblitities +=1
    limit +=1
total_combi = possibilities + not_possibilties #check if actually all possibilities were done
```

If you need permutations just change itertools.combinations to itertools.permutationss

Comment: It's a good idea thanks! Actually combinations is right choice instead of permutations. However it is far slower than the other two codes I've provided given that it iterates over all the possibile combinations and I cannot use it for practical purposes. Perhaps it can be implemented to give better performances.

Comment: Yeah was thinking itertools is too expansive. Is your number list sorted? if it is, there are some "search" methods that  you might want to consider and tbh I think you'd have better luck in a data science forum. If I think of something later I'll post it up. What size of data are you looking at?

Comment: Yes my number list is sorted. It's size is about 100 and usually the total number of addends is around 5-6, and never greater than 10.

Comment: Well I would endorse Cristian's answer :)